# regex condition against @version is never fulfilled

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have a docker-compose project for my application stack. I'm using [Logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) to forward docker logs of all services to a Logstash instance. Based on several regex conditions, I want to use different groks and other filters to get relevant data from the log message.

The problem is that Logstash always returns false for regex comparisons. My conditions never trigger.

My pipeline config is this:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}

filter {
    if [@version] =~ /1/ {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "regex" => "Version 1" }
        }
    }

    if [@version] == "1" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "equality" => "Version 1" }
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
    }
}
```

The `"regex" => "Version 1"` field is never added.

Example output:

```
logstash_1       | {
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1",
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-12-04T12:00:07.441Z,
logstash_1       |        "message" => "{\"hostname\": \"localhost\", \"container\": \"/deploy_scheduler_1\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-12-04T12:00:07Z\", \"source\" : \"stdout\", \"message\": \"Scheduler tick 2019-12-04T12:00:07.440Z\" }",
logstash_1       |           "host" => "deploy_logspout_1.deploy_default",
logstash_1       |           "port" => 51786,
logstash_1       |       "equality" => "Version 1"
logstash_1       | }
logstash_1       | {
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1",
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-12-04T12:01:07.505Z,
logstash_1       |        "message" => "{\"hostname\": \"localhost\", \"container\": \"/deploy_scheduler_1\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-12-04T12:01:07Z\", \"source\" : \"stdout\", \"message\": \"Scheduler tick 2019-12-04T12:01:07.504Z\" }",
logstash_1       |           "host" => "deploy_logspout_1.deploy_default",
logstash_1       |           "port" => 51786,
logstash_1       |       "equality" => "Version 1"
logstash_1       | }
logstash_1       | {
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1",
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-12-04T12:01:36.457Z,
logstash_1       |        "message" => "{\"hostname\": \"localhost\", \"container\": \"/deploy_app_1\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-12-04T12:01:36Z\", \"source\" : \"stderr\", \"message\": \"ERROR GET /article-asset/co-je-to-oop-a-proc-se-to-mam-ucit/oop-header.jpg/360x200 AssetError: No such file or directory: /home/teri/projects/docs/blog/co-je-to-oop-a-proc-se-to-mam-ucit/oop-header.jpg\\\\n    at getDocFilePath (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:64:15)\\\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\\\\n    at getAssetPath (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:76:23)\\\\n    at articleAssetsRoute (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:122:23)\" }",
logstash_1       |           "host" => "deploy_logspout_1.deploy_default",
logstash_1       |           "port" => 51786,
logstash_1       |       "equality" => "Version 1"
logstash_1       | }
logstash_1       | {
logstash_1       |       "@version" => "1",
logstash_1       |     "@timestamp" => 2019-12-04T12:01:36.489Z,
logstash_1       |        "message" => "{\"hostname\": \"localhost\", \"container\": \"/deploy_app_1\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-12-04T12:01:36Z\", \"source\" : \"stderr\", \"message\": \"ERROR GET /article-asset/proc-je-dobre-umet-programovaci-jazyk-java/java-header.jpg/360x200 AssetError: No such file or directory: /home/teri/projects/docs/blog/proc-je-dobre-umet-programovaci-jazyk-java/java-header.jpg\\\\n    at getDocFilePath (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:64:15)\\\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\\\\n    at getAssetPath (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:76:23)\\\\n    at articleAssetsRoute (/portal/packages/services/app/packages/server/routes/assetRoute.ts:122:23)\" }",
logstash_1       |           "host" => "deploy_logspout_1.deploy_default",
logstash_1       |           "port" => 51786,
logstash_1       |       "equality" => "Version 1"
logstash_1       | }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex conditional is correct, the problem is that you are testing it against `@version`, which is an internal logstash field.

If you create a field with the value of `@version` and test this field in your regex you will see that it works.

The following pipeline shows that your regex is working.

```
input {
    generator {
        lines => [
          "test message line"
        ]
        count => 1
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"test1" => "%{[@version]}" }
        add_field => {"test2" => 2 }
    }
    if [test1] =~ /1/ {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "regex1" => "regex test 1" }
        }
    }
    if [test2] =~ /2/ {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "regex2" => "regex test 2" }
        }
    }
    if [@version] =~ /1/ {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "regex" => "regex Version 1" }
        }
    }
    if [@version] == "1" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "equality" => "Version 1" }
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { }
}
```

Your output will be something like this

```
{
         "test2" => "2",
          "host" => "elk",
        "regex2" => "regex teste 2",
         "test1" => "1",
      "equality" => "Version 1",
      "sequence" => 0,
       "message" => "test message line",
      "@version" => "1",
        "regex1" => "regex test 1",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-12-10T02:04:23.021Z
}
```

The presence of the fields `regex1` and `regex2` shows that the regex works, it is just not working with the `@version` field for some unknown reason, this field is for logstash internal use only and can be safely removed in your pipeline.

If you want to use regex in your pipeline you should use it with a custom field or a field that exists in your documents.

Comment: Thanks. Initially, I was trying to solve a different problem which involved regex-testing my custom fields, but in trying to debug it I fell into this weird specific edge case. 
I edited the title of the question to better reflect the issue now that I know the cause.